# Android Studio gradle refresh destroys project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having some issues adding dependencies to my `build.gradle` in Android Studio.

Every time I click on the "Refresh all Gradle Projects" after changing the build.gradle, my project gets wiped:
[image: Gradle example]

Oddly, the files still exist on disk, but I can no longer build or make any code changes. Restarting Android Studio has no effect.

Am I doing something wrong? Is anybody else experiencing the same issue?

Using the latest Android Studio 0.3.1, a blank project and in-built Gradle wrapper.

Comment: I am facing a different AS refresh issue. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642271/why-doesnt-android-studio-refresh-ide-window-showing-remote-contents-after-mini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar one, when pointed wrong `build.gradle` file when importing project to intellij. You should point the root folder to import. The one with `settings.gradle` which contains `include:app` line.

Re-import project, pointing `MyProject` folder instead of `build.gradle` file directly.

```
MyProject/
 + app/
 + libraries/
    + lib1/
    + lib2/
```

Comment: I am facing a different AS refresh issue. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642271/why-doesnt-android-studio-refresh-ide-window-showing-remote-contents-after-mini